# Why is Gaussian distribution always chosen for smoothed analysis?

Tags: probability-distributions, algorithms, oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization

I came across the algorithmic perfomance analysis model of smoothed analysis. In all references that I read a Gaussian distribution was used for perturbation (e.g. Spielman and Teng 2004 for the Simplex algorithm). This lead me to the following questions:

- Why are always Gaussian distributions chosen? Do they have some unique properties making them preferable over other distribution, e.g. easier analysis? I know that one argument in favor of Gaussians is the fact that they are viewed as some sort of 'natural' noise. Therefore, there is a nice intuition of perturbating an instance $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ for example. However, is this really the only reason?
- How much does smoothed analysis depend on the actual probability distribution that is chosen? For example, average case analysis depends heavily on the distribution. In what manner does smoothed analysis behave? Is there any theory that supports robustness of smoothed analyses under different distributions?
- What examples are known where a smoothed analysis is conducted with other distributions? I could not find any. I am very grateful for any reference recommendations!

Thanks alot!

Comment: Not the only reason, but look for "central limit theorem" in wikipedia.

Comment: Here's some reasons reason why Gaussian random vectors are nice. If $X=(X_1,\dotsc, X_n)$  is a Gaussian vector then the components  $X_i$ are independent iff they are uncorrelated. (This in a certain says characterizes  the Gaussians). If $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a deterministic linear map then $AX$ is also Gaussian.  These two alow for easy computations of conditional expectations.  These are a few more elementary reasons.